# Monitoring directory changes with iwatch - getting new file's name not the full path?

Tags: linux, bash

Im using `iwatch` to monitor changes in the directory  - as soon as new video file is added to the directory I grab that file and using ffmpeg add overlay sound to it. Here is the script:

```
iwatch -e close_write -c "/root/bin/ffmpeg -i %f -i /var/www/video/sound.mp3 -map 0 -map 1 -codec copy -shortest /var/www/new/video/${%f:15}" /var/www/video
```

But I have a problem. I move newly created file to a different directory and I need to save it with the same file name, but `iwatch` has only `%f` variable which returns full path. Knowing that the first part of the path will always be `"/var/www/video/"` , I can use `${%f:15}` to get substring with the file name.

But the script below doesn't work - bash says `"bad substitution"`. So the problem is here - when I try to move the file to the new directory:

`/var/www/new/video/${%f:15}`

What is correct syntax, way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the output of the [basename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/basename) command:

```
/var/www/new/video/`basename %f`
```